# Can't install windows 7 SDK (require already installed .NET Framework 4)

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, visual-c++, failed-installation

I'm trying to install windows 7 SDK on Windows 8 and Windows 10 machines and got this error:
[image]

If I click on OK, I can't install VC++ compilers that I need because they are disabled =(

After this error I tried to install .NET 4 and got this error:
[image]

How to fix it?
Sometimes I can install this SDK on Windows 8 without error, but mostly I see these messages.

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions in the error message? In particular, have you fully uninstalled the pre-release version of the .NET Framework 4?

Comment: My crystal ball says that you have the preview version of .NET 4.6 installed.  Update it.

Comment: @HansPassant, It's clear windows 10 installation. What .NET I need to download and install? Can you give me a link?

Comment: Hmm, you'll have to make up your mind if it is 8 or 10.  Document the [registry key values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you see on machine that fails.  And do mention whatever else you installed on such a machine, anything that's a CTP or Preview is suspect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have encountered this problem, or at least what you describe sounds identical to what happened when I recently installed an older SDK on Windows 10. I was executing the `setup.exe` file at the top level of the download. And saw the same errors as you. But at the same level as `setup.exe` is a directory named `Setup`. Open that directory and execute the file named `SDKSetup.exe`. The installation should hopefully succeed when done this way.

The other SNAFU that can cause you trouble is if you already have the VS2010 MSVC runtime installed. You may need to uninstall it, install the SDK, and then re-install the VS2010 MSVC runtime.

Comment: Fixed the problem for me too! Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm currently having this problem too, but on Windows 7. What do you mean by executing the setup.exe at the top level? Where should it be executed?

Comment: @michael not where it is executed but which executable is run. Drop into the Setup folder and start the setup.exe that you find there.

Comment: Oh wow, that was simple. Didn't have to mess with any of the registry edits. I unzipped the the installer using 7zip and ran it from the setup folder. Thank you!

Comment: for me starting the Setup ended up with fail, but somehow subsequent normal start of websetup worked like a charm, contrary to that it did [NOT] before the "hack"

Comment: I was unable to do this using the websetup, it complained about a missing **WinSDK_amd64\WinSDK_amd64.msi**. I downloaded the GRMSDKX_EN_DVD.iso from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442 and tried it again. This worked as the referenced file is available from the iso.

Comment: @BertRegelink I observe the same error even while installing from ISO.

Comment: @Elephant You uninstalled all VS2010 MSVC runtimes?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes.