# Running windows recipe property handler sample

Tags: winapi, windows-10, failed-installation

I am trying to run the sample code for property handler([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)). It requires windows 7 sdk.

I am on windows 10 machine and as far as I know it comes with newer version of windows sdk. So do I need to install windows 7 sdk explicitly **or** just need the codes in the sample section that comes with the installation?

PS: Also it's failing repeatedly to install windows sdk 7 on windows 10 machine

Comment: Solve the PS like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423090/cant-install-windows-7-sdk-require-already-installed-net-framework-4

Comment: But it's surely best to install the Windows 10 SDK. The code should be forwards compatible.

Comment: Thanks, I followed that way too. But at the end there was another installation failure monster. That's why I was wondering if it is really needed to install windows sdk 7 or not. If it is not needed I would just download the code from somewhere(e.g. [here](http://example.com) )

Comment: Windows doesn't come with an SDK. The SDK is (and always has been) a separate download. You can use the Windows 10 SDK to build applications targeting any version of Windows starting with Windows Vista. See [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx) to learn how to set the minimum supported target.